# Cairo "Could not find libpng in the pkg-config search path"

Tags: gtk, cairo, directfb

I'm trying to install GTK-DFB and cairo is a requirement. When I try to build it from source, it throws:

```
checking for cairo's PNG functions feature... 
configure: WARNING: Could not find libpng in the pkg-config search path
checking whether cairo's PNG functions feature could be enabled... no
configure: error: recommended PNG functions feature could not be enabled
```

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have the libpng development packages installed; Installation is distribution dependent, but for debian derivatives following should be enough:

```
apt-get install libpng12-dev
```

Comment: I think on fedora, the package is called `libpng-devel`

Answer (score 7):

For me it helped to export the following variable in the shell:

```
export png_REQUIRES="libpng"
```

[Credit to this post](https://mattgwwalker.wordpress.com/2010/01/07/cairo-configure-issues/)

Comment: I had to do export png_REQUIRES="libpng16"

Comment: This worked for me.
  
  
`png_REQUIRES="libpng" ./configure`

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Ubuntu, another much faster solution is to do:

```
apt-get build-dep gtk+2.0
```